# Feedback on the shopping edge-case

Tags: discussion, cleanup

There is a database query I worked up:

http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/59563/finding-shoppers

In it, you will find a large selection of items that may or may not be subject to the 'shopping' exclusion of our current FAQ.

Rather than weed-whack the whole thing, I would like some feedback on what's good/bad/ugly in there.

Comment: Adding '%best%' somewhere in there would probably help; that word really hits the Shopping criteria for me.

Answer (score 1):

- [Any suggestions of a good registry cleaner?](https://serverfault.com/questions/10097/any-suggestions-of-a-good-registry-cleaner) (Clearly shopping. Clearly off topic.)
- [Tripwire policy suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/18302/tripwire-policy-suggestions) (Not shopping. Still a bad question. Too broad. Can't be salvaged. NARQ.)
- [Hardware and topology suggestions for iSCSI + GFS environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/17312/hardware-and-topology-suggestions-for-iscsi-gfs-environment) (Not exactly shopping. However, it's broad, asking for best practices, chatty, open ended and has four questions lined up like boxcars. Ultimately, NARQ.)
- [Web Application Vulnerability Scanner suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/45717/web-application-vulnerability-scanner-suggestions) (Clearly shopping. Not even a good shopping question. NARQ.)
- [Any suggestions on emitting Apache HTTPd access logs to CouchDB?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48713/any-suggestions-on-emitting-apache-httpd-access-logs-to-couchdb) (Not Shopping)
- [Need HAproxy + Varnish + nginx setup suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/51691/need-haproxy-varnish-nginx-setup-suggestions) (Not shopping.)
- [Proxying Flash connections - suggestions for tools/configurations?](https://serverfault.com/questions/66643/proxying-flash-connections-suggestions-for-tools-configurations) (Shopping. Also, not on topic for a professional SysAdmin site. Might possible be rewritten as "How can I cache web content for a LAN.")
- [remote movable workspace access workflow suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/72710/remote-movable-workspace-access-workflow-suggestions) (Shopping. Bad.)
- [Looking for VOIP hardphone suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/74252/looking-for-voip-hardphone-suggestions) (Shopping. *Really* bad.)
- [I need suggestions for a desktop solution for local scout group](https://serverfault.com/questions/70269/i-need-suggestions-for-a-desktop-solution-for-local-scout-group) (Shopping. Homework. What a stinker.)
- [Need a good dedicated webhost - suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/82637/need-a-good-dedicated-webhost-suggestions) (Shopping. Horrific.)
- [best connection suggestions or best practices for multi site data pull, expert advice needed](https://serverfault.com/questions/85582/best-connection-suggestions-or-best-practices-for-multi-site-data-pull-expert-a) (Not shopping. Scaling. DIE!)
- [OCS will not find SQL backend database, any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/89256/ocs-will-not-find-sql-backend-database-any-suggestions) (Not shopping. LEgit question. Finally.)
- [Email server - Disk quota sizes - suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/81744/email-server-disk-quota-sizes-suggestions) (Not shopping. Sizing. Open ended. Impossible to answer. Bad fit. Die!)
- [Need suggestions on making Network File Share, Internal Wiki, Google Docs, and emails searchable from a single location for my organization](https://serverfault.com/questions/83820/need-suggestions-on-making-network-file-share-internal-wiki-google-docs-and-e) (Real question - sort of. =/ )
- [Tool for finding Domain Names from a list of suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/98265/tool-for-finding-domain-names-from-a-list-of-suggestions) (Shopping question. Not even SysAdmin related. Die!)
- [Windows Server 2008 monitoring suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/96978/windows-server-2008-monitoring-suggestions) (Not exactly shopping for a product. I would have explained his options of polling SNMP or WMI. Borderline. The answers are crap. I'd kill it or totally rewrite it and provide a legit answer.)
- [Help Desk software suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/107675/help-desk-software-suggestions) (Shopping. Kill.)
- [Linux OCR server or development stack suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/117674/linux-ocr-server-or-development-stack-suggestions) (Angling for a product. I.e. Shopping. Outdated before it hits the ground. Kill.)
- [Windows SMTP server suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/109685/windows-smtp-server-suggestions) (Shopping questions post this question in their locker and look at it for inspiration. Needs multiple applications of denatured alcohol and grenades.)
- [Server crashed - corporate web application is down - considering moving to an online host - any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/115302/server-crashed-corporate-web-application-is-down-considering-moving-to-an-on) (Wow what a shopping question. Flame on.)
- [re: 3ware raid 10 (4drive) suggested stripe size suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/121365/re-3ware-raid-10-4drive-suggested-stripe-size-suggestions) (Not shopping. Sizing question. Subjective. Could be rewritten as "What should I take into account when choosing stripe sizes?" otherwise fire.)
- [Corporate IM with video that actually works, suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/124276/corporate-im-with-video-that-actually-works-suggestions) (Classic shopping question. Classic need for burnination.)
- [Any suggestions on Cluster management?](https://serverfault.com/questions/133683/any-suggestions-on-cluster-management) (Shopping. Broad. NARQ. Wondermod powers - ***activate!*** Form of: *all consuming river of brimstone!*)
- [Linux filesystem suggestion for MySQL with a 100% SELECT workload](https://serverfault.com/questions/135145/linux-filesystem-suggestion-for-mysql-with-a-100-select-workload) (Okay - kind of. Needs to be rewritten from "What is the best" to "What factors should I use to choose an appropriate file system.")

*Whew!* There's 25. Let's do some more!

- [Server Fax Farm - Need suggestions, or advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/134446/server-fax-farm-need-suggestions-or-advice) (Shopping. Lots of nope. Kill.)
- [Migrating master-slave MySQL database servers to 2 new servers, any tips or suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/138363/migrating-master-slave-mysql-database-servers-to-2-new-servers-any-tips-or-sugg) (Okay question. Best practisey, but... meh.)
- [Any suggestions for email delivery vendor?](https://serverfault.com/questions/139963/any-suggestions-for-email-delivery-vendor) (Page not found. Well done.)
- [.htaccess template, suggestions needed](https://serverfault.com/questions/139677/htaccess-template-suggestions-needed) (Not shopping, but sanctified bat guano was that a bad one. Looks like it was closed a few minutes ago.)
- [I am looking for a good load balancing (or reverse proxy) software for TCP and HTTP, any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/164882/i-am-looking-for-a-good-load-balancing-or-reverse-proxy-software-for-tcp-and-h) (Horrible shopping question. Kill.)
- [need high performance /bin/sort; any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/164275/need-high-performance-bin-sort-any-suggestions) (Shopping on the surface, but could be rewritten. "How do I sort 60 gigs of data efficiently?" or some such.)
- [Raid Caching configuration suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/171080/raid-caching-configuration-suggestions) (Not shopping, but terrible question. Should have been written as "What metrics should be taken into account when setting RAID caching options.")
- [connection sync suggestions with HAproxy and keepalived](https://serverfault.com/questions/170515/connection-sync-suggestions-with-haproxy-and-keepalived) (Not shopping. Could be written better, but meh.)
- [Old xSeries 8827 with SLES11, upgrade path suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/185395/old-xseries-8827-with-sles11-upgrade-path-suggestions) (Not exactly shopping. Chatty and open ended, yes. Not great for the Q/A format.)
- [Could anyone give me some suggestion about configure secure audit system](https://serverfault.com/questions/177429/could-anyone-give-me-some-suggestion-about-configure-secure-audit-system) (Not shopping. Tutorial link request. Those links die with time. Not good for a Q/A site. Apply fire directly to the forehead.)
- [LAMP webserver rental suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/183052/lamp-webserver-rental-suggestions) (Shopping is as shopping does. Dies in a fire.)
- [Wireless Repeater/Access point suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/184295/wireless-repeater-access-point-suggestions) (Not exactly shopping I suppose. I hate it on the surface. It should be rewritten to be more of a "How do I perform X" question, but even then...)
- [Business Continuity and Disaster Recovery Plans — suggestions for external help](https://serverfault.com/questions/187548/business-continuity-and-disaster-recovery-plans-suggestions-for-external-help) (Oooo, interesting. Not shopping, but rather "How do I shop." Okay, I'm cool with that.)
- [Any suggestion on MySQL services?](https://serverfault.com/questions/193740/any-suggestion-on-mysql-services) (Shopping. To quote Will Smith "Awww, hell no!")
- [Looking for open source anti-spam systems, any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/194867/looking-for-open-source-anti-spam-systems-any-suggestions) (Shopping. Chuck Testa.)
- [SVN hangs on commit - any suggestions for troubleshooting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/188272/svn-hangs-on-commit-any-suggestions-for-troubleshooting) (Not shopping. Seems good. Bad questions: 38. Legit questions: 3)
- [PE1800 upgrade suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/205321/pe1800-upgrade-suggestions) (Shopping. Needs to compelled to scream before dying in white hot jets of death.)
- [Outsourcing NOC to provide better 24x7x365 monitoring, suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/203809/outsourcing-noc-to-provide-better-24x7x365-monitoring-suggestions) (Horrible shopping question. Might be salvaged by asking "What should I look for in NOC providers." Maybe. Or maybe not.)
- [Deploying a small Rails app - suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/204709/deploying-a-small-rails-app-suggestions) (Not shopping. But has shoppy elements. I dunno. Questions seems a mess and not Q/A oriented. I'd leave it just because by this point I'm confused, angry and want to cry.)
- [suggestions for firewall/router project using *BSD or Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/215843/suggestions-for-firewall-router-project-using-bsd-or-linux) (It starts with the word "Suggestions" and ends with the single word question "Thoughts?" If that wasn't enough he asks for "other solutions" that might be out there. Shopping. NARQy. Does not contribute to ServerFault's longevity.)
- [I'm trying to set up a LAMP server so it's totally anonymous, any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/217230/im-trying-to-set-up-a-lamp-server-so-its-totally-anonymous-any-suggestions) (Not shopping. Yeah, it's okay. Could be worded better. "How can I guarantee the anonymity of web app users?")
- [SQL Server on EC2: Any pointers or suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/211076/sql-server-on-ec2-any-pointers-or-suggestions) (Not shopping, how it's chatty, open ended, subjective and asking for best practices. Perhaps it could be salvaged.)
- [Blog engine suggestion on IIS7 for multiple domains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/219554/blog-engine-suggestion-on-iis7-for-multiple-domains) (Close to shopping, but worded sort of okay. "How do I do this?" rather than "What products allow me to do this?" Let it live.)
- [Should I implement all “missing index” suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/222184/should-i-implement-all-missing-index-suggestions) (Not shopping. Legit question #4 out of the bunch!)
- [EXPLAIN with index suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/233318/explain-with-index-suggestions) (Shopping on the surface, but easily fixable. "How can I analyze a PostgreSQL EXPLAIN?" or something.)

That was 50 and enough for one night. I think I need to go cry into a pillow now.

The things my eyes have seen... :'(

Comment: So... that's a 10% hit ratio for good questions... Sounds like I'll need to schedule a tequila night if I look at this list, huh?

Comment: "Napalm, son. Nothing else in the world smells like that. "

Comment: So, I'm about to begin closing these and clearing the flags, but how do we want to close them? Off topic, not constructive or do we want to set up a canonical shopping question and close as dupes?

Comment: I'd just say offtopic @Sam - what could a canonical answer say that isn't already covered by the FAQ and/or Jeff's blog post about shopping questions (unless you fancy pasting that into an answer, I suppose...)

Comment: @Sam When it's something that's specifically precluded by the FAQ and the FAQ doesn't say what to do it, and is otherwise an answerable question (if we did that kind of thing around here), I OT-close.

Comment: Ok, thanks all. Will go through and close them when I get home shortly. Closing thy many questions on a phone doesn't sound like fun.

Answer (score 1):

Please feel free to disagree with and change any of my suggestions below.

- [HA suggestions for geographically separated sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/235708/ha-suggestions-for-geographically-separated-sites) (Not shopping, take out the suggestions keyword and it's fine.)
- [Administrator password lost for remote Windows Web Server 2008 R2, any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/241407/administrator-password-lost-for-remote-windows-web-server-2008-r2-any-suggestio) (Not shopping)
- [Need suggestions for a R/W distributed file system for a webserver cluster running Apache+PHP](https://serverfault.com/questions/247260/need-suggestions-for-a-r-w-distributed-file-system-for-a-webserver-cluster-runni) (Not sure - has tried various things and is looking for more options)
- [Debugging proxy with SSL MITM for Linux suggestion?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250277/debugging-proxy-with-ssl-mitm-for-linux-suggestion) (Not sure)
- [cPanel: Does not log any error - suggestion on host reply](https://serverfault.com/questions/251665/cpanel-does-not-log-any-error-suggestion-on-host-reply) (Not shopping)
- [What are suggestions for hardware,software,and active directory documentation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/241784/what-are-suggestions-for-hardware-software-and-active-directory-documentation)  (Shopping plain and simple)
- [Is there a GPO setting to enable/disable “show autocomplete suggestions” in word 2003?](https://serverfault.com/questions/259430/is-there-a-gpo-setting-to-enable-disable-show-autocomplete-suggestions-in-word) (Not shopping)
- [Changing phpMyAdmin so that it does not use a password…Any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/259718/changing-phpmyadmin-so-that-it-does-not-use-a-password-any-suggestions) (Not shopping)
- [exchange 2010 bacula backup suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/268146/exchange-2010-bacula-backup-suggestions) (sorta shoppingy)
- [MD1220 RAID Configuration suggestions for SQL Server](http://MD1220%20RAID%20Configuration%20suggestions%20for%20SQL%20Server) (not shopping, has no answers, could do with some love or a downcheck)
- [Need to convert WinXP desktop into a WinXP-based server, suggestions? (more details inside)](http://Need%20to%20convert%20WinXP%20desktop%20into%20a%20WinXP-based%20server,%20suggestions?%20%28more%20details%20inside%29) (Not shopping, just pain OT XP servers whoever heard of such a thing)
- [RAID array/hardware suggestions for SQL server for small business](https://serverfault.com/questions/295406/raid-array-hardware-suggestions-for-sql-server-for-small-business) (Not Shopping)
- [SSIS Consolidate huge amount of data - suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/303768/ssis-consolidate-huge-amount-of-data-suggestion) (Not shopping, no answers, needs some love or a downcheck)
- [Any suggestions for my iptables config?](https://serverfault.com/questions/314140/any-suggestions-for-my-iptables-config) (Not shopping)
- [Looking for a good file system monitoring tool. Any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/317351/looking-for-a-good-file-system-monitoring-tool-any-suggestions) (Shopping)
- [Dell PowerEdge t710 virtualization suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/319476/dell-poweredge-t710-virtualization-suggestions) (Not shopping)
- Any Nginx configuration suggestions for a site with a lot of traffic (Not shopping)
- [New system administrator - Any security suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/325684/new-system-administrator-any-security-suggestions) (not sure - are suggestions for dealing with a new sysadmin shopping ? It's probably a dupe though)
- [I'm seeing performance problems with postfix accepting mail when the queue is already large, any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/333727/im-seeing-performance-problems-with-postfix-accepting-mail-when-the-queue-is-al) (Not shopping)
- [Equipment suggestion for exhaust and cooling for a small server room](https://serverfault.com/questions/329766/equipment-suggestion-for-exhaust-and-cooling-for-a-small-server-room) (shopping)
- [Windows Server 2008 R2 + MSSQL Server R2 crashes once a week, suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/343229/windows-server-2008-r2-mssql-server-r2-crashes-once-a-week-suggestions) (not shopping)